# class PagingRx not found in Paging 3 library android

Tags: android

I am trying to make a list using paging 3 and Java Rx 3. In many examples uses this construction to cashing:

```
Flowable<PagingData<User>> flowable = PagingRx.getFlowable(pager);
PagingRx.cachedIn(flowable, viewModelScope);
```

My implementation:

```
def paging_version = "3.0.0"
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:$paging_version"
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-rxjava3:$paging_version"
```

But class PagingRx not found:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKaVF.png)

Rebooted to Gradle many times, cleared the cache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it will come in handy for someone.
In Kotlin, instead of PagingRx, you need to use

```
pager.flowable.cachedIn(scope)
```